# unable to get tile push notification in windows phone 8 from azure notification hub

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I am written code to send push notification to windows phone 8 by azure notification hub.
i am able to send to the toast notification to windows phone 8 and windows phone 8 also able to get notification . but when i am sending tile notification, it is sending tile notification successfully, but windows phone 8 is not getting this tile notification.

i already used  BindToShellTile and BindToShellToast at the time of getting the channel Uri and after that i am doing the registration by this channel uri and checked IDCAPPUSH_NOTIFICATION the capabilities in windowsphone porject manifest to allow the push notification.

Below my Code for Bind the Device to Tile And Toast.

```
public  void GetNotificationChannel()
{
    /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
    HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

    // The name of our push channel.
    string channelName = "ToastChannel";


    // Try to find the push channel.
    pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

    // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
    if (pushChannel == null)
    {
        pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

        // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

        // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
        pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

        pushChannel.Open();

        // Bind this new channel for toast  and tile notifications.
           pushChannel.BindToShellToast();
   pushChannel.BindToShellTile();


    }
    else
    {
        // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

        // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
        pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

        // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
        //    pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

    }
}
```

Below Code is sued to registered this device in notification hub.

```
// notification tois nothing but channel uri
    private static  async void WindowsPhoneRegistrations(string notificationToken)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var notificationHub = GetNotificationHubClient();
     // this wil retunr the notification hub client by using the notificationconnectionstring // and hub path              
                        var windowsPhoneRegistrationDescription = await notificationHub.CreateMpnsNativeRegistrationAsync();

                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Below code is for sending the tile notification

```
private static async void SendWindowsPhone8ToastNotification()
        {
            try
            {


                string windowsPhone8ToastFinalTemplate = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                                                            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\" Version=\"2.0\">" +
                                                              "<wp:Tile Id=\"txt1\" Template=\"IconicTile\">" +
                                                                "<wp:SmallIconImage>http://flyosity.com/images/_blogentries/networkicon/step2.png</wp:SmallIconImage>" +
                                                                            "<wp:IconImage>http://flyosity.com/images/_blogentries/networkicon/step2.png</wp:IconImage>" +
                                                                            "<wp:WideContent1 >This is sample</wp:WideContent1>" +
                                                                            "<wp:Count >1</wp:Count>" +
                                                                            "<wp:Title >Good</wp:Title>" +
                                                                            "</wp:Tile>" +
                                                                            "</wp:Notification>";            


                var notificationHub = GetNotificationHubClient();

                NotificationOutcome n = await notificationHub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(windowsPhone8ToastFinalTemplate));


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I am able to send the tile notification to notification hubs with out any exceptions and getting the status from notification hub after sending . but device is not getting the tile notification.

what i missed out or did mistake somewhere in this code to get the tile notification in windows phone 8. please help.